# What triple "tensor product" is this? Is it just isomorphic to a double tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, tensor-products

Consider the abelian groups $A = \Bbb{Q}^{\times}, B = \Bbb{Q}^{\times}, C = \Bbb{Z}^+$.  What if we formed a product like:

$A \star B \star C  = \text{Free}_{\Bbb{Z}}(A \times B \times C)$ quotiented by the subgroup generated by elements:

$$
(a, x\cdot y, u) - (a, x, u) - (a, y, u) \\
(a\cdot b, x, u) - (a, x, u) - (b, x, u) \\
(a, x,u + v) - (a, x, u) - (a, x, v)
$$

Is it just isomorphic to $A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} B \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} C$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Your notation $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is pretty confusing, you should probably not use it.